# Java - retrieve file, calculate, output to another file?

Tags: java

I'm new here so please excuse me if I make a mistake with the question asking process. I have researched my question for the last week and a half and haven't found what I'm looking for (although I feel like the answer is very close). I'm a student and have been working on an assignment using Eclipse for my Java class. I have written a code that takes information from one file, uses it in a calculation and now I need to output it into another file. This is where I am having difficulty. This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Program6 {

    private Scanner input;
    private ArrayList<Double> payRoll = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Program6 myObject = new Program6();

        myObject.openFile();
        myObject.readFile();
        myObject.calculateRecords();
        myObject.closeFile();

    } 

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            input = new Scanner(Paths.get("Program6.txt")); 
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        try {
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                payRoll.add(input.nextDouble());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException elementException) {
            System.err.println("File improperly formed. Terminating.");
        } catch (IllegalStateException stateException) {
            System.err.println("Error reading from file. Terminating.");
        } 
    }
    public void calculateRecords() {
        System.out.printf("%10s%25s%15s%19s", "Before Payroll",
                "Raise Percent",
                "Raise Amount",
                "After Payroll\n");

        double raisePercent;
        double raiseAmount;
        double totalBeforePayroll = 0;
        double totalAfterPayroll = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < payRoll.size(); i++) {
            if (payRoll.get(i) > 70000) {
                raisePercent = 4;
            } else if (payRoll.get(i) > 50000) {
                raisePercent = 7;
            } else {
                raisePercent = 5.5;
            }
            raiseAmount = payRoll.get(i) * raisePercent / 100;

            System.out.printf("%12.2f%21.1f%18.2f%17.2f%n",
                    payRoll.get(i), raisePercent, raiseAmount, payRoll.get(i) + raiseAmount);

            totalBeforePayroll += payRoll.get(i);
            totalAfterPayroll += payRoll.get(i) + raiseAmount;
        }

        System.out.printf("%nTotal amount of raises: $%,.2f%n",
                totalAfterPayroll - totalBeforePayroll);
        System.out.printf("Average raise percent : %.0f%%",
                (totalAfterPayroll - totalBeforePayroll) * 100.0 / totalBeforePayroll);
        System.out.printf("%nAverage raise amount  : $%,.2f%n",
                (totalAfterPayroll - totalBeforePayroll) / payRoll.size());
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        if (input != null)
            input.close();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly is not working? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: im not trying to be rude but it seems like googling "java write to file" gave me a fine result. here is a link: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/java-write-to-file/

Comment: @Mr.Yellow looks like he doesnt know how to write his results to a file

Comment: Just google "java write list to file" and you'll find more literature than you actually need. Plenty of ways to do so, and plenty of examples online.

Comment: Consider using [`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) for file system operations...

Comment: @Mike, could you please tell us what the file looks like you are reading from and what the expected outputfile is supposed to look like

Comment: Hey, thanks guys for the quick responses. That article looks to be very helpful, but what I'm having difficulty wrapping my brain around is how to take information from one file, performing a calculation with it and then creating a new file with that information. The examples in the article show how to take take information that has been typed in and saving it to a file. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to output just the payroll amount after adding the raise amount.

You can write a void method `writeFile()` in which you loop through your list and append every entry to an empty file.

For this I'm going to be using the `BufferedWriter` class, but you are free to chose whatever class you like. I'm going to proceed with the `BufferedWriter` example though.

So what we need to do in our `writeFile` method is setting up the `bufferedwriter`. This is done like this:

```
BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("path here" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "filename.txt"));
```

Replacing "path here" by wherever you want to save your file. One example would be to replace it by System.getProperty("user.dir") which is the users working directory.

`System.getProperty("file.seperator")` would be a `\` in Windows. But using `System.getProperty("file.separator")` will make it work on different systems as well.

So:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "filename.txt"));
```

Now you can loop through your list and append every entry to the writer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < payRoll.size(); i++){
    bw.append(payRoll.get(i));
}
```

After that you can and should "close" the `bufferedwriter` using:

```
bw.close();
```

The method would look something like this:

```
BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("path here" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "filename.txt"));

for (int i = 0; i < payRoll.size(); i++){
    bw.append(payRoll.get(i));
}
bw.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Alan! This definitely helps. It's still taking me a moment to understand the concepts explained, but it's beginning to make sense and has helped. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are welcome @Mike. If this did help, you may upvote and/or mark the answer as "most helpful". would definetly appreciate it :)